# Using iPad and iPhone storyboards in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have created an app with a storyboard in Xcode and I now want to create an iPad version. I successfully created an iPad storyboard, but it currently runs with the code from the iPhone version.

The issue I am having is that the code for the iPhone is still running with the iPad storyboard. I would like to duplicate the iPhone code and adjust it for the iPad.storyboard, but I am not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a screenshot for you:

[image]

So switch the tabs and assign the appropriate storyboard. and make sure it is set to universal.

Comment: meda, thank you but i have already done this. the issue I am having is that the code for the iphone is still running with the ipad storyboard. i would like to duplicate the iphone code and adjust it for the ipad, but i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The same code runs, its the storyboard that are different

Comment: exactly, i dont want the same code to run, i want to be able to make the ipad storyboard run with a different code, but i do not know how to get the seperate new code to run for the ipad.storyboard

Comment: Then add more classes to your project and assign each view controller with its own class. Very easy

Comment: @JamesF. why did you unaccept the answer? if you needed more help you should tell me

Comment: i had messed around with the universal setting under deployment info and and a dialog window popped up and created a folder for me. i now would like to get that back but when i switch devices to universal i no longer get an option to create a folder for ipad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59371/discussion-between-meda-and-james-f).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you now have two storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad, which are both working properly, but you want to modify part of the code just for the iPad version.

You should duplicate the classes you want to edit for the iPad version of your app and assign those new classes to the corresponding ViewControllers of the iPad storyboard.

Of course, you are still making a single, universal app.